# How to access window rectangle of a non-desktop Windows-App

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I would like to access the window dimensions of an Windows-App / a non classic desktop app over a desktop C# console application.

If it would be a desktop app I could easily use this simple line of code:
`User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect)`

This line of code fails to retrieve the rect for a modern Windows-App. 
Is there any way to get the window rect or modify the window dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Windows.UI.Xaml.Window currentWindow = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current;`
`Windows.Foundation.Rect rect = currentWindow.Bounds;`

rect.X and rect.Y will give you the coordinates.